# Two Jenkins: Await remotely triggered job

Tags: jenkins, build

I'm using two Jenkins machines (v.1.651.1) - one on a Mac lets call this one **Jenkins A** with a **Job A** and the other a Windows machine **Jenkins B** with a **Job B**.

Main entry point is at Jenkins A where Job A is triggered. This job builds something, puts it on a shared network directory and then triggers Job B on Jenkins B via remote API. Job B continues building something independently.

In the meantime Job B is acquiring the intermediate files from the network share and starts building something, too. If something goes wrong here - I could stop Job A via remote API.

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement a wait at Job A so that it only turns successfull if Job B has been finalized.

Multijob Plugin seems to be what I'm looking for, but this doesn't work over multiple Jenkins instances, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a master - slave Jenkins.

- Mac machine: master
- Windows machine: slave

Just notice the Jenkins web GUI on the Mac machine. Then install the "CloudBees Build Flow plugin".

You can split Job A if you want. We have 3 jobs.

- Job A1 : builds something, puts it on a shared network directory.
- Job B: building something independently.
- Job A2: what do you need here?

Create Build flow job like this:

`build("Job A1")
 build("Job B")
 build("Job A2")`